# Read Multiple Files In C++

Tags: c++, freopen

I am trying to read two files "ListEmployees01.txt" and "ListEmployees02.table". But the program reads only the "ListEmployees01.txt" file and `cout` is just from that file.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen("ListEmployees01.txt", "r", stdin);
    string s;
    while (getline(cin, s))
        cout << s<<endl;
    fclose(stdin);
    freopen("ListEmployees02.table", "r", stdin);
    while (getline(cin, s))
        cout << s<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `freopen` to open the files as the C stream `stdin` instead of creating an `std::ifstream` C++ object to read the files?

Comment: Both `freopen` expressions attempt to assign to stdin, which is not guaranteed to be assignable.

Comment: Thanks. I will use ifstream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) instead of changing `std::cin`'s behavior.

Comment: Can I use freopen instead of ifstream?

Comment: @DuongPhan ***Why?*** What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: Thanks. I just like freopen more ... In this problem, i will use ifsrtream

Answer (score 1):

In your case , in the case of second file you are using the stdin which is already closed by below line , hence it is a dangling pointer after file close

> fclose(stdin)

You can use fopen instead of freopen for the second file.

Please check the below paragraph from www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/

> If a new filename is specified, the function first attempts to close
>   any file already associated with stream (third parameter) and
>   disassociates it. Then, independently of whether that stream was
>   successfuly closed or not, freopen opens the file specified by
>   filename and associates it with the stream just as fopen would do
>   using the specified mode.

Answer (score 1):

### I would do the following using `fstream`

```
#include <fstream>

void readAndPrint(const char *filename) {

    std::ifstream file(filename);

    if (file.is_open()) {

        std::string line;
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            printf("%s\n", line.c_str());
        }
        file.close();

    }

}

int main() {

    readAndPrint("ListEmployees01.txt");
    readAndPrint("ListEmployees02.table");

    return 0;
}
```

If you must use `freopen`, then have a look at `man freopen`, or the C++ reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen .